# How to create dynamic subdomain using PHP and htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have one problem:
I want to set up PHP and htaccess to make dynamic subdomains. And I can not figure out how.
Currently my URL looks like this:

```
www.exemple.com/index.php?subdomain=mike&component=content&id=26&title=people-love-apps
```

I need it to look like this:

```
www.mike.exemple.com/content/26/people-love-apps.html
```

I know it can be done but I do not know a solution how to do it.
Is very important to me with $ _GET [] functions to read parameter in the URL.

The problem is that users on my site make their web site and get a free domain (sub-domain) automatically. This should be automatic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't *make* dynamic subdomains with `.htaccess`

You will need to configure the apache virtual host to accept requests for multiple domains

See the [Apache documentation - Using Name Based Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html#using)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

Adding the wildcard subdomain `*.example.com`, your PHP application will receive all requests for any domain below `example.com`, ie `garbage.example.com`, `busted.example.com`, `llama.example.com`, etc.

[Creating Wildcard Sub Domain Using Apache VirtualHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566226/creating-wildcard-sub-domain-using-apache-virtualhost)

[Multiple Domains to One Virtual Host | Wildcard Host (shared hosting)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621819/multiple-domains-to-one-virtual-host-wildcard-host-shared-hosting)

[Apache default virtual host for multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831460/apache-default-virtual-host-for-multiple-domains)

At this point, your application will have to determine the validity of the subdomain and display the appropriate error for unknown subs.

From there, parse the domain for `mike`.

Comment: What about just using server aliases for each subdomain?

Comment: Yes, but that is still vhost config, not `.htaccess`

Comment: **The problem is that users on my site make their web site and get a free sub-domain automatically. This should be automatic.**

Comment: Yes, the `*` in the server alias will accept ALL subdomains of the domain `example.com`.  When the user is assigned the subdomain, the server will automatically respond on the subdomain and your application determines the validity of the subdomain.

Comment: In your vhost.conf add `ServerAlias *.example.com`. Then, your application can call `parse_url` http://us2.php.net/parse_url to get the requested subdomain

Comment: after create vshost do not forget to re-write the DNS table. at least if you are local, edit your /etc/hosts file and add the right entry there!

Answer (score 3):

OF COURSE you can interprete dynamic subdomains with htaccess.
The following rule will solve the problem.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/content/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-])\.html /index.php?subdomain=%1&component=content&id=$1&title=$2  [L]
```

so anyone visting

```
 www.mike.exemple.com/content/26/people-love-apps.html
```

will see the content of

```
www.exemple.com/index.php?subdomain=mike&component=content&id=26&title=people-love-apps
```

Comment: Tell me about something, do I need to configure apache for this?

Comment: No, you don't need any apache configuration.