# How to create subdomain dynamically without going cPanel

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, subdomain, cpanel

I am working on laravel and need to create subdomain using laravel dynamically without going cPanel or server setting.

Say here I have abc.xyz.com and I want create {subdomain}.abc.xyz.com . where subdomain will dynamic.

To access I have Use following code in laravel route.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'abc.xyz'], function()
{
    return 'Main page will be loaded';
}); 

Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.abc.xyz'], function()
{
    return 'Subdomain page will be loaded';
});
```

Also I have searched, but just found only way by .htaccess .

Is it the only way to do this or is there any other ways also to create subdomain dynamically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706904/how-to-create-dynamic-subdomain-using-php-and-htaccess

Answer (score 3):

your hosting should support wildcard subdomain features https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9191/29/how-to-create-wildcard-subdomain-in-cpanel

Comment: Great link for Cpanel's Admins. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago I wanted to create a subdomain dynamically in my project. I was coding in Core PHP. I think this could be helpful to you or someone else. 
Here is my solution.

1. I created wildcard subdomain as shown by @Rockers Technology in previous answer

[image]

Then Step 2: On at Home Directory of my project I created createSubDomain.php file with following code:

```
$subDomain = "mytestdomain";
    $cPanelUser = 'user_name';
    $cPanelPass = 'password';
    $rootDomain = 'main_domain_name';



//  $buildRequest = "/frontend/x3/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=" . $rootDomain . "&domain=" . $subDomain;


//$buildRequest = "/frontend/paper_lantern/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=" . $rootDomain . "&domain=" . $subDomain . "&dir=public_html/code/" . $subDomain;
$buildRequest = "/frontend/paper_lantern/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=" . $rootDomain . "&domain=" . $subDomain . "&dir=public_html/code/";

$openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
if(!$openSocket) {
    return "Socket error";
    exit();
}

$authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;
$authPass = base64_encode($authString);
$buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "\r\n";

fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
while(!feof($openSocket)) {
fgets($openSocket,128);
}
fclose($openSocket);

$newDomain = "http://" . $subDomain . "." . $rootDomain . "/";
echo $newDomain;
```

After running this code on webserver, you can check in subdomain section, that a new subdomain gets created as shown in following picture:

[image]

Comment: How does it work with 2-way authentication enabled?